# Can mSata or M.2 SSD in be instaled Wi-FI or DVD ports?

Tags: ssd, msata, m2-connector

I have a standard Acer Aspire 7739G laptop. I want to buy a mSATA, but I don't know if my laptop supports them. I don't have an mSATA port in my motherboard. I don't know if an mSSD or M.2 SSD can installed in the WiFi port (motherboard port) or in the DVD port (motherboard port).

[image]
<sup>**This is the wireless socket in my motherboard. Can I install an mSATA drive here?**</sup>

Comment: mSSD or M.2 SSD are not the samething.

Answer (score 0):

No. An M.2 SSD will only be compatible with laptops that feature an M.2 slot.